When i changing mac address, i have to turn off and on wifi. But how with ethernet?
I'm making a code to change the mac address temporarily, everything seems to work, but the mac address changes only, for example, in the example of wifi, not when I turn off the network card, but when I go to the wifi icon and click turn it off and then turn it on and I connect to the network again. And now the question is how to do it with Ethernet? I tried using the code to disable the network card, but then the mac address does not change anything at all, it is only the default one.
This code is written in C# .NET 4.7.2.
private static async Task ChangeMacAddresses()
{
    var networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    foreach (var nic in networkInterfaces)
    {
        if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet || nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
        {
            string newMac = GenerateRandomMacAddress();
            await SmoothPrint($"Changing MAC address for {nic.Name} to {newMac}", 10);

            // Znalezienie odpowiedniego identyfikatora klasy
            string classId = GetNetworkInterfaceClassId(nic);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(classId))
            {
                await SmoothPrint($"Failed to find class ID for {nic.Name}", 10);
                continue;
            }

            // Zmieniamy adres MAC
            string changeMacCommand = $@"reg add ""HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{classId}"" /v NetworkAddress /t REG_SZ /d {newMac} /f";
            await ExecuteCommandsAsAdmin(new[] { changeMacCommand });
        }
    }

    await SmoothPrint("MAC addresses changed.", 10);
}


private static string GetNetworkInterfaceClassId(NetworkInterface nic)
{
    // Odczytaj identyfikator klasy z rejestru systemowego
    // Należy zastąpić poniższy kod rzeczywistym sposobem pozyskiwania identyfikatora klasy
    // lub znaleźć odpowiedni sposób uzyskania identyfikatora na podstawie sprzętu

    // Przykład: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" - trzeba zmienić na rzeczywisty identyfikator
    return "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
}

private static string GenerateRandomMacAddress()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
    rand.NextBytes(macAddr);
    macAddr[0] = (byte)(macAddr[0] & (byte)0xFE); // set the multicast bit to 0
    macAddr[0] = (byte)(macAddr[0] | (byte)0x02); // set the local bit to 1
    return string.Join(":", macAddr.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
}

I tried turning the network card off and on but to no avail.
